# SDN setup: Mininet with VMs + OpenDayLight

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, sdn, mininet, opendaylight

I'm new to SDN programming. I wanted to post it on `serverFault` or `Network Engineering`, but looks like they don't have some of the keywords.

Anyways, although I knew SDN concepts before, but I want to try in practice with simulations and programming and see how things really work. I need technology and software package recommendations that can be best to use:

- I've been told I should use `Mininet` which is basically a network
  simulator with built-in SDN support which works based on VMs.
- And for SDN controller I've been told `OpenDayLight (ODL)` is a great
  choice nowadays which has many plugins, features and supports.

Can I integrate Mininet with ODL? What is the relation of Mininet with VMs? Can mininet VMs run standalone say Ubuntu VMs? So basically how should I use all these together?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no integration between Mininet and ODL. You use them for different purposes. Mininet is for the switch part, ODL is for the controller part.

[Mininet](http://mininet.org) is for simulating network switches. You need an SDN enabled (it means openflow supported) switch and an SDN controller for SDN testing. With mininet you can create a network topology with openflow supported mininet switches and you can set ODL or any other SDN controller (such as [ryu](https://osrg.github.io/ryu/), [onos](http://onosproject.org/software/), [floodlight](http://www.projectfloodlight.org/floodlight/) etc.) as their SDN controller.

It is not clear why you are asking about VMs. Mininet has a [VM image](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Mininet-VM-Images) but it is just for easy installation. You can also install it from source code.

[Mininet Walkthrough page](http://mininet.org/walkthrough/) could be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Yavuz, your descriptions were useful. I am new to all these and I've been told Mininet must run VMs! Thanks for clearing this for me.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can integrate the SDN-ODL and Mininet onto a VM.
    I am a researcher in ODL. I have worked on Mininet and ODL.

```
My suggestion to you is;
[1] Install a VM.
[2] Try to install SDN Hub, if not- install Ubuntu 14.0 LTS which is stable version till date. 
[3] Install the packages.

*** I have been working on Ubuntu from past two years.. and it is working very effieciently.
```